# Erro ao recarregar uma página com Angular

Tags: angular

Estou com uma aplicação com Angular que se eu clicar no botão com:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/clientes']">
```

ele funciona normalmente, mas se eu recarrego a página, dá esse erro:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   NodeInvocationException: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for
>   ClienteService! **Error: No provider for ClienteService!** at Error
>   (native) at injectionError
>   (C:\Users\Frai\Desktop\estudo\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:12066:90) at
>   noProviderError
>   (C:\Users\Frai\Desktop\estudo\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:12104:12) at
>   ReflectiveInjector_.module.exports.ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull
>   (C:\Users\Frai\Desktop\estudo\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:13546:19) at
>   ReflectiveInjector*.module.exports.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault
>   ...

Segue o codigo do Client Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ClienteService } from '../../Services/cliente.service';
import { ICliente } from '../../Models/cliente.interface';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
selector: 'app-cliente',
templateUrl: './cliente.component.html'
})

export class ClienteComponent implements OnInit {

    clientes: ICliente[] = [];
    cliente: ICliente = <ICliente>{};

    //formulario
    formLabel: string;
    isEditMode: boolean = false;
    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(private clienteService: ClienteService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = fb.group({
            "nome": ["", Validators.required],
            "endereco": ["", Validators.required],
            "telefone": ["", Validators.required],
            "email": ["", Validators.required]
        });

        this.formLabel = "Adicionar Cliente";
    }


    ngOnInit() {
        this.getClientes();
    }

    private getClientes() {
        this.clienteService.getClientes().subscribe(
            data => this.clientes = data,
            error => alert(error),
            () => console.log(this.clientes)
        );
    }


    onSubmit() {
        this.cliente.nome = this.form.controls["nome"].value;
        this.cliente.endereco = this.form.controls["endereco"].value;
        this.cliente.telefone = this.form.controls["telefone"].value;
        this.cliente.email = this.form.controls["email"].value;

        if (this.isEditMode) { // editar
            this.clienteService.editCliente(this.cliente)
                .subscribe(response => {
                    this.getClientes();
                    this.form.reset();
                });
        } else { // incluir
            this.clienteService.addCliente(this.cliente)
                .subscribe(response => {
                    this.getClientes();
                    this.form.reset();
                });
        }
    };

    edit(cliente: ICliente) {
        this.formLabel = "Editar Cliente";
        this.isEditMode = true;
        this.cliente = cliente;
        this.form.get("nome")!.setValue(cliente.nome);
        this.form.get("endereco")!.setValue(cliente.endereco);
        this.form.get("telefone")!.setValue(cliente.telefone);
        this.form.get("email")!.setValue(cliente.email);
    };

    cancel() {
        this.formLabel = "Adicionar Cliente";
        this.isEditMode = false;
        this.cliente = <ICliente>{};
        this.form.get("nome")!.setValue('');
        this.form.get("endereco")!.setValue('');
        this.form.get("telefone")!.setValue('');
        this.form.get("email")!.setValue('');
    };

    delete(cliente: ICliente) {
        if (confirm("Deseja excluir essa cliente?")) {
            this.clienteService.deleteCliente(cliente.id)
                .subscribe(response => {
                    this.getClientes();
                    this.form.reset();
                })
        }
    };
}
```

Edit: Consegui com:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-cliente',
templateUrl: './cliente.component.html',
providers: [ClienteService]
})
```

Comment: Você adicionou o `.js` do seu `ClienteService` no `HTML`?

Comment: Você esta provendo o `ClienteService` no módulo onde seu `ClienteComponent` esta declarado?

Answer (score 0):

> Error: No provider for ClienteService! Error: No provider for
>   ClienteService!

Esse erro ocorre sempre que voce usa um service que nao foi declarado como provider no app-component ou nao foi devidamente importado la.

Answer (score 0):

As duas maneiras mais comuns de se resolver é:
- Colocando o Service no providers.
- Importar o componente no module e no routing.